# alert not shown with $.getJSOn asp.net MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a an actionlink in my masterlayout like this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Order Your Free Report 1", "CheckValue", "Product", null,new { id = "checkExists" })
```

I have an action method like this :

```
  public ActionResult CheckValue() {
            bool result = true;
            ViewData["checkCondition"] = true;
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and  function like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkExists').click(function () {
     $.getJSON(this.href, function (result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result) {
                alert('the record exists');
            }           
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I click the link, alert is not shown. But If I use like this:

```
 $(function () {
  $('#checkExists').click(function () {

        var condition =new Boolean('@ViewData["checkCondition"]');
        if (condition) {
            alert("message");
        }
   return false;
    });
});
```

It works. Please suggest why first one is not working ?

Comment: Have you used something like Firebug or other browser debugger to see whether the HTTP request is even being made?  Are there any errors reported anywhere?

Comment: check using firebug what is the value of `href` attribute of you link?

Comment: @3nigma: link looks like this in firebug html window: <a id="checkExists" href="/Product/CheckValue">Order Your Free Report 1</a>

Comment: @Pointy: I just noted that request is made in case of jquery  $.getJson. but not incase of javascript alert.

Comment: Well yes, of course; if you just do the second one, there's no ajax call, and so no HTTP transaction. Is the HTTP request normal or does it have an error?  Does the result appear to be correctly JSON-encoded?

Comment: $.getJSON fails silently for me when the JSON string in the response is invalid.  Can you check to make sure that the JSON you are returning is valid?  Also, is the request from $.getJSON completed successfully (no 400 or 500 errors)?

Comment: @Wizard: yes I get true as response

Comment: trying using the browser debug tools to step into the script and see if a/ the getJSON function succeeds & b/ what the value of result is

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I'm not seeing anything wrong with your code, which is why I suspected an invalid JSON response or unsuccessful HTTP request.  Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions other than you can try using `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON`.  With `$.ajax` you have a bit more control over processing responses, so it might help you troubleshoot the issue.  Out of curiousity, how did you check that your JSON response is valid?

Comment: @Wizard: I am checking using Firebug. What will be alternate $.ajax call for this $.getJSON ?

Comment: Open Firebug and see real value in href.. If you application in virtual folder, it might contain something now you expecting;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping `this` into `$(this)`

```
$(function () {
    $('#checkExists').click(function () {
     $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function (result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result) {
                alert('the record exists');
            }           
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the ajax version

```
   $(function () {
      $('#checkExists').click(function () {

       $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr('href'),
         type:'GET',
         success: function (result) { ... },
         dataType: 'json',
         error:function(jqXhr,textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert("Oops ");
             alert(jqXhr.responseText);
             alert(jqXhr.status);
         }
            });
          return false;
        });
    });
```

try this and tell what alerts show up